# Check if editable field is edited jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I track which row is edited when user edited a `editable` `textarea` in `jqgrid`.

```
$("#accJqgrid").jqGrid({
    url: path,
    postData: { deviceId: deviceId, loadId: 'Hardware' },
    datatype: 'json', 
    mtype: 'POST',
    width: 650,
    height: 150,
    colNames: ['', 'ID', '', '', 'Description', '', '', 'Comments', 'Delete'],
    autowidth: true,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'state', width: 30, sortable: false, hidden: true },
        { name: 'ID', width: 30, sortable: false, hidden: true },
        { name: 'catalogId', width: 30, sortable: false, hidden: true },
        { name: 'Save', width: 30, sortable: false, formatter: saveAccessoryData },
        { name: 'Description', width: 250, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Search', width: 30, sortable: false, formatter: searchAccessory },
        { name: 'License', width: 0, sortable: false, hidden: true },
        { name: 'Comments', width: 380, sortable: false, edittype: 'textarea', editable: true, editoptions: { rows: "2", cols: "73", dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).attr("maxlength", "250"); } } },
        { name: 'Delete', width: 50, sortable: false, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox', editable: true, align: 'center', classes: 'deleteBackgroundColor' }
    ],
    rowNum: 50,
    pagination: true,
    rowList: [25, 50, 100],
    pager: $('#accJqgridpager'),
    gridComplete: function () {
        }
    },
    afterInsertRow: function (id, data) {
        jQuery('#accJqgrid').jqGrid('editRow', id);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to my no question about jqGrid. You have just textarea control and want to track the caret movement. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/263796/315935) for example. Is it what you need?

Comment: No i want to track which table row is edited. Since it is a textarea i cannot track if it is edited or not.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. First of all it's important to know which editing mode (inline editing, form editing or cell editing) you use? Do you use `multiselect: true` or not? It's better to post the jqGrid which you use.

Comment: I changed the code. Please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeSelectRow callback to trace the current editing rows:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    alert('rowid=' + rowid);
}
```

One remark to your code: I would you recommend never use `afterInsertRow` which make the filling of the jqGrid slowly. Instead of that you can add `gridview: true` option and call `editRow` inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $myGrid = $(this);
    $myGrid.find('>tbody>tr.jqgrow').each(function () {
        $myGrid.jqGrid('editRow', this.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I know if the edit has been saved, in any of the cells, before submitting the grid? Right now, I am getting all the HTML code of a drop down when user is still in edit mode but submits the jqgrid by clicking a save button.

Comment: @b.g: You can use `getGridParam` to get `savedRow` parameter. The parameter contains array of elements. Every element corresponds the currently editing row. The exact format of the elements from `savedRow` depends on the version of jqGrid, which you use, and from the editing mode (cell editing or inline editing). You can use `savedRow` to detect which rows are currently editing.